# How to index logs from java program (log4j2) into elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logging, log4j2

How can I index logs directly from log4j2 into elasticsearch index?

Main.class:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String... args) {
        logger.info("This is an info message.");
        logger.error("This is an error message");
    }
}
```

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="trace"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I want to know if there is a way to inject logs directly into elasticsearch, by adding dependency and appenders to logger.

Comment: As of now ,its not you have to use shipper tools such as fluentd ,logstash & etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my plugin: https://github.com/rfoltyns/log4j2-elasticsearch. It does exactly what you need.

Be sure to configure the `IndexTemplate` and use log4j2-*:(,2.10] to avoid https://github.com/rfoltyns/log4j2-elasticsearch/issues/9. I'll release a fix for that soon.